# Find and Replace a string and add spaces in Vi editor

Tags: unix, search, replace, vi

There is a file with fixed length of 150 Until 1st comma it's 50 characters and so on. So I want to replace A with XYZ and add 48 spaces in vi editor.

**Before:**

```
A          ,B         ,3           
A          ,C         ,4
```

**After**

```
XYZ        ,B         ,3
XYZ        ,C         ,4
```

Answer (score 0):

Use following command

:s/A    /XYZ/g

pls check http://vimregex.com/ on how to use regexes

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I want that to be dynamic. When I mean dynamic, I want to replace A with XYZ and add spaces for the remaining length. I just gave this as an example. I can count the number of spaces every time. There can be 100 characters in place of A and 47 characters in place of XYZ.